# Ansible got stuck while running shell command for creating symbolic link

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

For below task for creating symbolic link, ansible stuck and no output for 5 mins

```
- name: Registering the service my-service
      shell: > 
        sudo ln -s {{KARAF_HOME}}/bin/karaf-service /etc/init.d/
```

On ctrl+c it output below

```
♥Process WorkerProcess-19:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/executor/process/worker.py", line 118, in run
    self._rslt_q
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 138, in run
    res = self._execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 561, in _execute
    result = self._handler.run(task_vars=variables)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/action/shell.py", line 27, in run
    result = command_action.run(task_vars=task_vars)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/action/command.py", line 24, in run
 [ERROR]: User interrupted execution
```

i also tried below option but again facing error

```
file: src="{{KARAF_HOME}}/bin/my-service" dest="/etc/init.d/" state=link  owner=root group=root
```

it produce below error

```
fatal: [my-host]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "gid": 0, "group": "root", "mode": "0755", "msg": "refusing to convert between directory and link f
or /etc/init.d/", "owner": "root", "path": "/etc/init.d/", "size": 4096, "state": "directory", "uid": 0}
```

Update:
For running shell its looking for password, but i tried below as recommended by @imjoseangel

```
- file: become=true src="{{KARAF_HOME}}/bin/my-service" dest="/etc/init.d/my-service" state=link
```

But getting below error

```
"msg": "Unsupported parameters for (file) module: become Supported parameters include: attributes,...
```

Comment: Have you read the error message before pasting it here?

Answer (score 0):

Hi the destinatios must be a file and not a directory.

```
file: src="{{KARAF_HOME}}/bin/my-service" dest="/etc/init.d/my-service" state=link  owner=root group=root
```

Comment: now getting below error , i mentioned root but in below error its providing my ssh account as owner
fatal: [my-host]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "gid": 1002, "group": "imran", "mode": "0775", "msg": "chown failed: [Errno 1] Operation not per
mitted: b'/opt/karaf/bin/my-service'", "owner": "imran", "path": "/opt/karaf/bin/my-se
rvice", "size": 15819, "state": "file", "uid": 1002}

Comment: Do you have permissions in that directory? Do you want to do it with your user or with root? `become: True`

Comment: its not supported
"msg": "Unsupported parameters for (file) module: become Supported parameters include: attributes,...

Comment: What indent do you have for `become`?

Comment: - file: become=true src="{{KARAF_HOME}}/bin/my-service" dest="/etc/init.d/my-service" state=link

Comment: An you add to your question please?